# Escape backslash in JSON String in JavaScript and Python 2.7

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-2.7, escaping

Here is my JSON string to loads or Parse:

```
json_str = '[{"executable_path": "C:\\GCafeClient\\CafeClient.exe", "arguments": "-package 100003"}]'
```

This was valid if I test it [in json formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) or [here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)(Also it makes sense right--I have escaped backslash.

But when I do `json.loads(json_str)` in Python 2.7 or `JSON.parse(json_str)` in JavaScript in Chrome. I got errors:

```
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 25 (char 24)
```

and

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token G
```

If I put it this way, then it will work for both:

```
json_str = '[{"executable_path": "C:\\\\GCafeClient\\\\CafeClient.exe", "arguments": "-package 100003"}]'
```

Why is this so?

Comment: That's why: https://xkcd.com/1638/

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but using a forward slash for a directory separator (yes, even on Windoze) saves a lot of pain.

Comment: What's wrong with the output when you use '\\\\'?

Comment: Nothing. the print result is fine. (I removed that part in the edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the '\' twice, the first time for the Python/JavaScript literal and the second time for JSON.

So `"C:\\GCafeClient"` will evaluate to `"C:\GCafeClient"`, which is not accepted JSON as it contains an unescaped '\' and will throw an error.

On the other hand `"C:\\\\GCafeClient"` will evaluate to the JSON being `"C:\\GCafeClient"`, therefore the '\' is escaped and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I will just post my own understanding here for this question:

```
# python
json_str = '[{"executable_path": "C:\\\\GCafeClient\\\\CafeClient.exe", "arguments": "-package 100003"}]'
# which is equivalent to
json_str = r'[{"executable_path": "C:\\GCafeClient\\CafeClient.exe", "arguments": "-package 100003"}]'
# and JSON format requires backslash to be escaped
```